# Microsoft's "Print to PDF" truncates embedded images

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, office365, print-to-pdf

I am trying to print a document, which contains an embedded image located in front of the text. Unfortunately, in PDF version it appears truncated/cropped.

How to overcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Printing" to PDF from Word can be dicey, I've also had issues like you are describing.

Try instead to Export as PDF: Go to the File menu, choose Export, and you should see an option to Create a PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

wysiwyg's answer is better then mine, but you can also try to use PanDoc, in case if Word's build-in convertation tool fails.

To create a PDF, you will need to install LaTeX first - see MacTeX on OS X or MiKTeX on Windows. Then do:

```
pandoc test.docx -s -o test.pdf
```